# SQL statement generated by CRecordSet.Delete()

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to see the SQL statement generated by `CRecordSet.Delete()`?

Comment: Does your SQL server keep logs? Can it?

Comment: I don't know. Where I can find it?

The reason I want to see the sql statement is because the var.Delete() throws an ORA-01861 error.